# Removing current page from browser history

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I'm building a text editor in my website, the workflow is as follows.

1. In `/list`, the user picks an entry they want to edit from a list which takes them to `/edit/[article_id]`.
2. The user does their work, and then clicks submit.
3. The server processes the thing, and redirects them back to `/edit/[article_id]` which by now reflects the edited work. The server also activates a flash message on the page to indicate the edit was successful.

By this point, the user probably wants to go back to `/list` and clicks the browser's Back button. This will take them back to the editor repeatedly depending on how many times they submitted.

I've tried putting a Back button somewhere on the page, but a good many users simply ignore it.

I'd rather not make the submission posted via AJAX, since that would also affect the flash message system.

What I like to do, is replace the last entry on the history list when the user submits, without changing its length. Is it possible?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Try this**

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

after using `replace()` the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

Comment: So, I should use `window.location.replace()` in `/list`?

Comment: url = window.location.href

Comment: Excellent. As simple as it gets and exactly what is needed 

Comment: wow. Thats cool

Answer (score -4):

Use window.close():

```
close();
```

Note: the current tab is implied. This is equivalent:

```
window.close();
```

or you can specify a different window.

So:

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

with HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>
```

You return false here to prevent the default behavior for the event. Otherwise the browser will attempt to go to that URL (which it obviously isn't).

Comment: That wasn't the question