# how do i disable browser back button after login?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
def login(request):
    if request.session.has_key('is_logged'):
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':

        email = request.POST['email']
        psw = request.POST['psw']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=psw)

        if user is not None:

            auth.login(request, user)
            request.session['is_logged'] = True
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'invalid user name or password')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')

def logout(request): 
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

how do i disable browser back button after login? is it good idea to disable backbutton from preventing logged users ? after login it redirects to the home page and from home page if i click browser back button it goes the previous page login.

Comment: You can use some JavaScript for that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42918895/67579), but that thus would mean that you login with an AJAX request. Furthermore browsers can of course override this behaviour.

Comment: You can use decorators in your views.py, Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923027/disable-browser-back-button-after-logout/6935774)

Answer (score 0):

> is it good idea to disable backbutton from preventing logged users ?

I don't see the problem with users being able to go back to the login page. If you don't want them to log onto an other account while being already logged in, you could just redirect the users or throw an error page if you detect that the user is already logged in.