# Clear all back stack, page navigation history for specific domain when user logout in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one website from abc.xyz.com, when an user named A login from login page into my site, my site navigate to home page, when user A click on profile button, my site navigate to profile page which display information of this logged in user A.Then, user A logout, my site clear all session of user A and navigate to login page, user A login with a difference account as user B from login page. Now in homepage, user B press back button of browser and user B can see the profile page of user A. How can I clear back stack and page navigation history when user A logged out so user B cannot see the profile page of user A?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of API is limited to extensions, you can't do this from website script https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/deleteUrl. You can prevent saving url in history by using `location.replace` [Removing current page from browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918837/removing-current-page-from-browser-history).

It seems you have a bigger problem, though. You server doesn't require authorization when serving user specific data. Clearing browser history isn't gonna cut it :|

Comment: my server does require authorization, but when user B press back button, the profile page doesn't reload